# Remove columns in which factors appear only once in a matrix column in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix with different factors in columns. I want to drop columns in which factors appear only once in a column in R.

My example matrix is:

```
n.mat <- structure(c("M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "Y", "Y", "M", "M", 
"Y", "Y", "Z", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "X", "Y", "Y", "F", "F", 
"F", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "D", "D", "D", "E", "E", "E", "E"), .Dim = c(8L, 
6L), .Dimnames = list(c("r1", "r2", "r3", "r4", "r5", "r6", "r7", 
"r8"), NULL))

  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
r1 "M"  "M"  "M"  "A"  "A"  "C" 
r2 "M"  "M"  "M"  "A"  "A"  "D" 
r3 "M"  "Y"  "X"  "A"  "A"  "D" 
r4 "M"  "Y"  "Y"  "A"  "A"  "D" 
r5 "M"  "Z"  "Y"  "A"  "A"  "E" 
r6 "F"  "F"  "F"  "A"  "B"  "E" 
r7 "Y"  "F"  "F"  "A"  "B"  "E" 
r8 "Y"  "F"  "F"  "B"  "B"  "E"
```

The desired output (only leaving column 5):

```
n.mat <- structure(c("A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "B", "B", "B"), .Dim = c(8L, 
1L), .Dimnames = list(c("r1", "r2", "r3", "r4", "r5", "r6", "r7", 
"r8"), NULL))

  [,1]
r1 "A" 
r2 "A" 
r3 "A" 
r4 "A" 
r5 "A" 
r6 "B" 
r7 "B" 
r8 "B"
```

My code:

```
n.mat[, apply(n.mat, 2, function(x) sort(table(x), decreasing = TRUE)[] == 1)]
```

but it doesn't seem to work, what do I have to change?

Comment: You code is close - try `n.mat[, apply(n.mat, 2, function(x) !any(tabulate(factor(x)) == 1)), drop = FALSE]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try the code below

```
n.mat[, !rowSums(sapply(unique(c(n.mat)), function(x) colSums(n.mat == x)) == 1), drop = FALSE]
```

or

```
n.mat[, apply(n.mat, 2, function(x) !any(table(x) == 1)), drop = FALSE]
```

giving

```
   [,1]
r1 "A"
r2 "A"
r3 "A" 
r4 "A"
r5 "A"
r6 "B"
r7 "B"
r8 "B"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try one of these definitions of minlen together with the last line. This keeps columns for which the minimum number of occurrences of any element's value exceeds 1.

```
# pick one
minlen <- function(x) sort(table(x))[[1]]
minlen <- function(x) min(lengths(split(x, x)))
minlen <- function(x) min(tapply(x, x, length))
minlen <- function(x) min(table(x))

n.mat[, apply(n.mat, 2, minlen) > 1, drop = FALSE]
```

Answer (score 0):

An vectorized option with `rowSums`

```
tbl <- table(c(col(n.mat)), c(n.mat))
n.mat[, !rowSums(tbl == 1 & tbl != 0), drop = FALSE]
#   [,1]
#r1 "A" 
#r2 "A" 
#r3 "A" 
#r4 "A" 
#r5 "A" 
#r6 "B" 
#r7 "B" 
#r8 "B"
```